# AVAudioPlayer won't play in didEnterRegion

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, cllocationmanager

I'm asking the question like that because a UIAlertView will go off.  Just not the AVAudioPlayer.  Here's my code:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region

{
    NSLog(@"MapViewController - didEnterRegion");

    LocationReminder *theLocationReminder = [self.locationReminders objectForKey:region.identifier];

    NSError *error;
    NSURL *theUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:theLocationReminder.audioURI];

    NSLog(@"theUrl = %@",theUrl);

    AVAudioPlayer *thePlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:theUrl error:&error];

    NSLog(@"thePlayer.url = %@",thePlayer.url);

    [thePlayer play];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"entered region..." message:@"You have Entered the Location." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"  otherButtonTitles: nil];
    alert.tag = 2;
    [alert show];
}
```

I checked the logs on the device after testing and while the Alert View does indeed show while I'm walking around testing it, the AVAudioPlayer wont play even though it has the correct URL.

I should mention that while I have enabled audio in the plist under Required Background Modes, I'm still in the app (so backgrounding wouldn't be an issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not maintaining a reference to `thePlayer` so it is getting deallocated (assuming you are using ARC). Possibly add a property in your class `@interface` block like

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

and then instead of the line you have do

```
self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:theUrl error:&error];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but honestly, that must be it.  I'll give it a whirl now and write back.  I should know better too..

Comment: Nuts.  That didn't do it.  I was so hopeful too.  I'm going to check the logs.

Comment: Hm assuming that the object holding the `player` reference isn't also deallocated, I don't see anything obvious in your code. You should maybe implement the AVAudioPlayerDelegate protocol, set yourself as delegate, and see if the error callback is getting called.

Comment: It just worked but I'm trying to figure out why.  At some point tho, it will have to work when the app is in the background.  Given that, will a property in the view controller be enough?  Where should I put the AVAudioPlayer in order to keep it around when the app is in the background?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the accept. A view controller probably isn't the most appropriate place for that, if nothing else audio won't play while you do other things in the app. Try to put it in a singleton type object perhaps, or perhaps retained in the application delegate. I'm not a fan of the latter as it couples lots of your code to the specific application and makes reuse in other apps a pain, but YMMV.

Comment: You got it - while I'm not sure a property in the VC will work, at least your answer got me thinking about scope.  I'm thinking of going with the AppDelegate but like you that just feels wrong.  I wonder what Apple's suggested technique is for Object Scope When Running In The Background.

Comment: Another important thing is that the UIBackgroundMode needs to be set to audio.  I'm still researching this but it suuuure seems important.